# How to send Multiple parameter from form using submit button one without Ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I have form consist item_id , item_name , item_price and item_bio at the end have input tybe submit like this

```
<form method="POST" action="menu.php"> 
<div class = 'cont'>
        <span>item_name</span>
        <hr />
        <img id='img_order' src='img/$item_pic' alt='ss'>
        <p id='price'>price : 3.14 </p>
        <p id='bio'>this item is ... </p>
        <input type= 'submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add to Order' name = 'order' />
    </div>
```

and in the "menu.php"

```
if(isset($_POST['addToDatabase'])){
   quert = "INSERT INTO table_name('item_id','item_name','item_price','item_bio' )VALUE('$item_id' , '$item_name','item_price','item_bio')";
```

}

How store the item_id , item_name , item_price and item_bio in variables and put in values to send the database ?

Note : don't care about syntax if thes code is not running 
I just want tell me answer the quastion

Comment: there are no input elements for the variables you've mentioned...

Comment: I asked how to input elements this variables

Comment: Any PHP forms tutorial would show you the basic idea

Answer (score 1):

With them html Form like this

```html
<form method="POST" action="menu.php">
  <div class='cont'>
    <span><input type="text" name="item_name" value ="item name" readonly/></span>
    <hr />
    <img id='img_order' name="img_order" src='img/$item_pic' alt='ss'>
    <p id='price'>price : <input type="text" name="item_price" value="3.14" readonly/> </p>
    <p id='bio'><textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="40" readonly>This item is ...</textarea></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="itemid" />
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Add to Order' name='addToDatabase' />
  </div>
```

And your php code would look like this for pdo prepared Statements and a established Connection
db.php

```
<?php
  $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1';
  $user = 'root';
  $password = '0000';

  try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

It is recommended to put the db.php file in a subfolder, so please do that and edit the require accordingly
and the php file that uses the send data

```
<?php
 require ('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['addToDatabase'])){
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO table_name('item_id','item_name','item_price','item_bio' )
   VALUE( (?, ?,?, ?)");
  $stmt->execute([$_POST['item_id'], $_POST['item_name'],$_POST['item_price'],$_POST['item_bio']]);
  $stmt = null;

}
?>
```

Comment: nothing this is made by **$stmt->execute()** inside the brackets come the data you received by POST. all wporks the only thing you need is a mysql connection https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php but inseta of $dbh is used $pdo

Comment: can you write all code i nead 
I mean Want to show all step beginning from connection to database
localhost , root , 0000 , test

Comment: I edited my answer but you should still foloow my link for understanding it better.